# Save twitter data streams to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to save real time tweets to cassandra, however, Eclipse is showing a marker in this line:

```
CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(tweets).writerBuilder("Twitter","tweets", CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(tweets.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

Eclipse does not recognize mapToRow() and javaFunctions() even though i've imported all the packages.
I am using the 1.4.0 Cassandra connector in order to be compatible with spark version. 
I've seen people using this approach,
`javaFunctions(, .class).saveToCassandra("java_api", "sales");`
but the documentation tells that it is deprecated with the new versions.

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spark Cassandra Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkStreamingIntro.html

Comment: @KishoreKumarSuthar thnx, this is the scala version..i couldn't get any java documentation!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978125/comparison-between-different-methods-of-executing-sql-queries-on-cassandra-colum